# How to draw custom graphs in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, graph, android-graphview

Here is an example of a graph:

[image: Graph image]

How can I draw this type of graph in an Android layout?

Comment: You'd probably have to draw directly on a SurfaceView. or http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Comment: Simple example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543739/how-to-draw-a-graph-in-android-using-graphview/26562713#26562713

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jjoe64/GraphView](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView) can be used in your case.Samples are Also Given.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a third party library such as achartengine

https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/

Here's their home page

http://www.achartengine.org/

Here's a tutorial on Line Graph

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ThKImy6PPM