# Draw Graph in android using Graphview?

Tags: android, graph, scrollview

I want to create a bars graph on my android application. 
I need the graph on a **scrollView**.

I've tried already [GraphView](http://android-graphview.org) and [AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com).

Comment: GraphView is easy option to start with

Comment: @Nabin I've tried this but I'm canoot understand it. I need a guide for it.

Comment: you need scrollview horizontally inside graph? @Ido Naveh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

**The new update to the GraphView doesn't support this approach**

**Using GraphView:**

I have made a function below that takes three arrays as parameter. First one takes X-axis labels, next takes Y-axis labels and last takes values to be plotted.

**Code**

```
private void renderGraph(String[] xAxis, String[] yAxis, float[] data) {

        GraphViewData[] data = new GraphViewData[xAxis.length];//this class is defined below

        double v = 1, w = 1;
        int num = xAxis.length;
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            v = data[j];
            data[j] = new GraphViewData(j, v);
        }
        GraphViewSeries example1 = new GraphViewSeries(data);
        GraphView graphView = new BarGraphView(this, "GRAPH TITLE");
        graphView.setVerticalLabels(yAxis);
        graphView.setHorizontalLabels(xAxis);
        graphView.addSeries(example1);
        example1.getStyle().color = Color.BLUE;
        graphView.setScalable(true);
        graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setTextSize(18);
        graphView.setScrollable(false);
        graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setGridColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setGridStyle(GridStyle.VERTICAL);
        graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setNumHorizontalLabels(5);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graphz);//graphz is defined in layout
        layout.addView(graphView);
    }
```

**GraphViewData class:**

This class is little bit variant from the one given in documentation.

```
   public class GraphViewData implements GraphViewDataInterface {

    private double x, y;

    public GraphViewData(double x, double y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public double getX() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.x;
    }

    @Override
    public double getY() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.y;
    }
}
```

**P.S.**

Call this method as:

```
String[] xAxis = {"RED","WHITE","BLUE","GREEN"};
String[] yAxis = {"GOOD", "AVEGRAGE", "BAD"};
String[] data = {"1", "2", "1","2"};
renderGraph(xAxis, yAxis, data);
```