# Cannot use Graph View library in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-graphview

I want to plot graph in Android. So, after some research I found that GraphView is a good one. So, I followed this (http://www.ssaurel.com/blog/create-a-real-time-line-graph-in-android-with-graphview/ ) tutorial , but I am unable to use graphView in eclipse. I have added the jar file using Properties->Java BuildPath->Libraries and added the jar file.

When I run the project, I am getting fatal error.  I will be glad to provide any other information regarding this,

I am using Eclipse Neon on windows 7.

[image: SS of first few lines from logCat]

EDIT- This the SS of graphical layout in xml file.

[image]

EDIT- Complete layout of the project file

[image]

Java code-

```
package com.ssaurel.testgraphview;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.Viewport;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
  private LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;
  private int lastX = 0;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // we get graph view instance
    GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    // data
    series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
    graph.addSeries(series);
    // customize a little bit viewport
    Viewport viewport = graph.getViewport();
    viewport.setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
    viewport.setMinY(0);
    viewport.setMaxY(10);
    viewport.setScrollable(true);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   // we're going to simulate real time with thread that append data to the graph
   new Thread(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
       // we add 100 new entries
       for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {
             addEntry();
           }
         });

         // sleep to slow down the add of entries
         try {
           Thread.sleep(600);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           // manage error ...
         }
       }
     }
    }).start();
   }

   // add random data to graph
   private void addEntry() {
     // here, we choose to display max 10 points on the viewport and we scroll to end
     series.appendData(new DataPoint(lastX++, RANDOM.nextDouble() * 10d), true, 10);
   }

}
```

xml code-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ssaurel.testgraphview.MainActivity" >

    <com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView
    android:id="@+id/graph"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543739/draw-graph-in-android-using-graphview/26562713#26562713

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I would suggest to use Android Studio and then use gradle to make use of the library. Eclipse is deprecated.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong...you are using jjoe64/GraphView....make sure you have added the required android library(jar or lib prjt) in the project.Please can you specify the name of jar that added?

Comment: @ShadowDroid. Yes. You are right. And I have added the jar GraphView-4.0.0. I even tried with the latest version- GraphView-4.2.1.jar, but still the problem is persisting.

Comment: Please create libs folder for the project and copy paste the jar directly into the libs folder in the Project Structure

Comment: @ShadowDroid That was the first thing I tried. I created libs folder and added the jar file directly. It didn't work.

Comment: Sorry but I tried the sample and is working for me  by adding jar only in the libs folder. Please make sure you removed it elsewhere. Also add the complete layout file in the question

Comment: @ShadowDroid. I edited my question and added the complete layout file. I hope that's what you asked ?

Comment: Please add the xml code of the layout file and and the code that you wrote in correspongind activity. Please do not attach screenshot.

Comment: Edited the question and added the codes.